# Javascript to Load and Save Files Temporarily

Tags: javascript, storage

I am working on a thing where I have an iframe. I want to load a static javascript file to this iframe every time user clicks on a button. The javascript file is located at the server and because this is the static file so I would like it to be downloaded to the client once and every time user clicks on the button it just loads this file into iframe without calling server.

I know AJAX can be used to download this file contents and how to add script tag to the iframe but I am not sure where should I temporarily save the contents and then put the contents back into a file to put that file as script tag into iframe.

You can consider [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBgDt/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just dumping the data into a cookie?

Comment: This can be done for sure but it has size limits right? 5 MB?

Comment: I didnt read your question clearly enough sorry, a cookie will store about 4kb max, clearly not enough for a whole javascript! (unless its tiny i guess...). There are client side storage methods available with the new html5 spec, localstorage would probably do it, but then you're limited by brower.

Comment: Another approach would be to setup caching. That way you can just treat the file as normal, and the browser would handle the rest itself

Comment: You said you want it to download from the server once, and then after that use a local copy yeah? Well that's exactly what caching will do

Comment: Assume I download the file using jQuery.ajax() and it returns file contents as response now how would it cache it?

Comment: You would have to configure it in your server, how you do that depends on which server you're using but it isnt difficult. After that you can forget about it and just treat the file as usual. If caching is set up correctly, the first time you ajax the file the request will hit the server, any subsequent times the clients browser will simply fetch the local cached copy and return that

Comment: Would you refer me to the link where I can read how this should work with Apache server? I am using WAMP and MAMP.

Comment: I'm not too hot on apache, a quick google turned this up but it might be a bit basic http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/cache/